# RE: USART @115200 on PIC18 explorer (PIC18F8722)

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I have tried to initialise UART1 and communicate with a PC with no success @115200, as the SPRTG register, which needs to be 4.4253, cannot be so without introducing a large error.

The board has three oscillators: 10MHz, 12MHz and the last is a watch type crystal at 32 kHz. The solution to the problem as much as I can think of it is to use the watch type clock oscillator to decrease the error to < 3%, but I was unable to find out how that can be done

The current oscillator is HSPLL (I have no clue as to the difference between HS and HSPLL).

Code:

```
#include <p18f8722.h>
#include <usart.h>

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config OSC = HSPLL // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Two-Speed Start-up disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = SBORDIS // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset enabled in hardware only (SBOREN is disabled))
#pragma config BORV = 3 // Brown-out Voltage bits (Minimum setting)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF // Watchdog Timer (WDT enabled)
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768 // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3L
#pragma config MODE = MC // Processor Data Memory Mode Select bits (Microcontroller mode)
#pragma config ADDRBW = ADDR20BIT// Address Bus Width Select bits (20-bit Address Bus)
#pragma config DATABW = DATA16BIT// Data Bus Width Select bit (16-bit External Bus mode)
#pragma config WAIT = OFF // External Bus Data Wait Enable bit (Wait selections are unavailable for table reads and table writes)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = PORTC // CCP2 MUX bit (ECCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config ECCPMX = PORTE // ECCP MUX bit (ECCP1/3 (P1B/P1C/P3B/P3C) are multiplexed onto RE6, RE5, RE4 and RE3 respectively)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF // Low-Power Timer1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RG5 input pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = ON // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP enabled)
#pragma config BBSIZ = BB2K // Boot Block Size Select bits (1K word (2 Kbytes) Boot Block size)
#pragma config XINST = OFF // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF // Code Protection bit Block 0 (Block 0 (000800, 001000 or 002000-003FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF // Code Protection bit Block 1 (Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF // Code Protection bit Block 2 (Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF // Code Protection bit Block 3 (Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP4 = OFF // Code Protection bit Block 4 (Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP5 = OFF // Code Protection bit Block 5 (Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP6 = OFF // Code Protection bit Block 6 (Block 6 (01BFFF-018000h) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP7 = OFF // Code Protection bit Block 7 (Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF // Write Protection bit Block 0 (Block 0 (000800, 001000 or 002000-003FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF // Write Protection bit Block 1 (Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF // Write Protection bit Block 2 (Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF // Write Protection bit Block 3 (Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT4 = OFF // Write Protection bit Block 4 (Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT5 = OFF // Write Protection bit Block 5 (Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT6 = OFF // Write Protection bit Block 6 (Block 6 (01BFFF-018000h) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT7 = OFF // Write Protection bit Block 7 (Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-007FFF, 000FFF or 001FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit Block 0 (Block 0 (000800, 001000 or 002000-003FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit Block 1 (Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit Block 2 (Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit Block 3 (Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR4 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit Block 4 (Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR5 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit Block 5 (Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR6 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit Block 6 (Block 6 (018000-01BFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR7 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit Block 7 (Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-007FFF, 000FFF or 001FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

/* For later
void init5UART(){
    Open1USART(USART_TX_INT_OFF&
    USART_RX_INT_OFF&
    USART_ASYNCH_MODE&
    USART_EIGHT_BIT&
    USART_SINGLE_RX&
    USART_BRGH_LOW, 125000); // solve for x in 5 = 10000000/(16*(x+1))
    delay_1s();
} */

// Init UART to 115200 Baud 
void initUART(){
    // set up USART connection
    Open1USART(USART_TX_INT_OFF&
    USART_RX_INT_OFF&
    USART_ASYNCH_MODE&
    USART_EIGHT_BIT&
    USART_SINGLE_RX&
    USART_BRGH_HIGH, 5); 
    delay_1s();
}

int Dready(){
    return DataRdy1USART(); // is there anything read to be read?
}

char readUART(){
    return getc1USART(); // get data
}

void writeUART(char c) {
    putc1USART(c); // put char
}

void closeUART() {
    Close1USART(); // close USART connection
}
```

Comment: The watch crystal is almost certainly 32 **KHz**, not 32 MHz, and so will not work as a baud rate reference without a PLL multiplier which is probably not available for that source.  Some micros are able to do 115200 from a 12 MHz crystal, but yours may not be one of them.  HSPLL would be a potentially multiplied version of the higher speed oscillator and may be your route to a solution. Perhaps you'll get an answer from someone who has configured this specific part before.

Comment: I did some minor clean-up of this question - we generally don't put thanks in the body of the question (it's OK in comments)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39646c.pdf), at \$F_{OSC}\$ = 40MHz, you can achieve 114.943kBPS which is only -0.22% off.

[image]

So, it's just a matter of using the PLL to increase the external oscillator frequency from 10MHz to 40MHz and you're there. (Hint - see section 2.5 of the datasheet)

Comment: According to the table, even with a 10MHz clock one can get down to -1.36% error (look at the 3rd column)

Comment: @hli True enough. That being said, one may as well take advantage of the faster execution that the PLL allows, so long as the supply is up to the task and the device is OK thermally.